# C# dictionary is not working, when comparing input to key value pairs only last pair works

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I'm trying to do basic login-password verification and I made a dictionary to store credentials. If I input last login and password it works but for any other pair, it doesn't.

```html
<h1 class="header">"@success"</h1>
<input placeholder="Login" @bind="@login" />
<input placeholder="Password" @bind="@password" type="text"/>
<button @onclick="@check">check</button>
```

```cs
@functions
{
    private string password,login;
    bool success=false;
    private Dictionary<string, string> creds = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"1","2" },
        {"3","4" },
        {"5","6" }
    };




    private void check()
    {

        foreach (var item in creds)
        {
            if (login == item.Key && password == item.Value)
            {
                success=true;
            }
            else
            {
                success=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works as expected for last pair (5 and 6), success changes to true.
For the other pairs, it doesn't work, success is still false.

Comment: Step back and think about your loop. Where would you maybe insert a break statement when the task of the loop is accomplished??

Comment: An important side note: don't store passwords. Instead, store (salted) hashes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a "break;" after success=true; and you are done.

Right now, after beeing successfull, you check the next credentials and they are invalid and reset your 'success'.

Answer (score 2):

Try to debug the statement. The for-each statement is processed for each entry in creds. Which means that each iteration, the success variable is set to true/false again. When the inputs equals the first or second pair of creds, it will be overwritten in the last iteration which results in success being set to false.

You need to break out of the foreach loop when success is set to true.

```
success = false;
foreach (var item in creds)
{
   if (login == item.key && password == item.value)
   {
      success = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop once you set success = true

It works only in the last pair because it happens to be the last pair and you stop :)

You better write the code like this:

```
success = creds.ContainsKey(login) && cred[login] == password;
```

On another note I hope this is not production code, you should not store passwords in plain text in memory or anywhere else...